# How i can add a button on the cart page that will allow the customer to "Empty The Cart". In bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

How i can add a button on the cart page that will allow the customer to "Empty The Cart".  Script will empty contents of the cart.

Comment: Hi Sophia, Please reference [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need to know quite a few more detail if you'd like our help. Please edit your original post when you have more to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use the management api to do this, because that would require authentication. You need to use the [storefront cart api](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/storefront/carts) I believe.

You would need to call `GET /api/storefront/carts` and get the id of the cart, and then call `DELETE /api/storefront/delete/{id}`.

Alternatively you could mimic the native functionality by looping through all the cart items to build a request for `POST /remote/v1/cart/update`.

The template file for cart in cornerstone is `templates/pages/cart.html`

Answer (score 0):

you could create the button in the template and use a script to call this endpoint: DeleteACart https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/carts/cart/deleteacart, to erase an entire cart.